# Double asterisk regex reports as invalid

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I'm trying to find an indeterminable amount of text, including punctuation, between a pair of two asterisks (i.e. `**This text, please**`) using `findText` along with a regular expression. The script should then act upon both the asterisks and the enclosed text. My code is as follows:

```
function main() {
  var search = body.findText('(\*\*)+([.*]+)+(\*\*)');
  if (search === null) {
    DocumentApp.getUi().alert('No text was found that required formatting.');
  } else {
    function second() {
      if (search !== null) {
        search = body.findText('(\*\*)+([.*]+)+(\*\*)');
        search.setBold(true);
        body.replaceText('\*\*','');
        second();
      } else {
        DocumentApp.getUi.alert('Formatting completed!');
    }
  };
}
};
```

I'm working upon the assumption the `findText` only finds the first instance of a search pattern.
Now, I'm fully aware that my regular expression won't work due to capture groups not being supported, but what other way is there to 'phrase' such as search? Would it be possible to do this with three separate search with an offset if it can't be done with a single regular expression?

Comment: Your .findText regex is not correct for matching between double asterisks.  It should be more like: `\*\*(.*)\*\*`.

Comment: Also, .findText will return either true or false.  You should be checking for true or false.  not "null".

Comment: and what is .replaceText()?  Is that a function from some other plugin or script?  How about just use javascript `.replace()`?  And search.setBold()? you're calling .setBold() (whatever that is) on a boolean value..  You're code has too many problems..

Comment: @MElliott I tried the initial as code first, but as previously stated capture groups aren't supported by the function `.findText`. Additionally, `.findText` is returned as a string value (which leads me to wonder if this is actually going to work as intended, and what other method could be used). The functions being used are documented here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body?hl=fr-FR#findText%28String%29

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to announce that, but it look like the operation you are trying to perform is impossible. as said in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body?hl=fr-FR#findText%28String%29) the function findText do not support any regExp, and the one you are building don't look to be supported.
this is my reformulation of your regExp: http://regex101.com/r/eN6vT9 : *{2}.*?*{2}
But because of the restrictions it's not supported, the only thing I where cappable of matching is a single star.
More over when you find a match the action of putting the match in bold is not working. It bold the all paragraph. The only possible workaround that I found here is to extract the text perform the regexp on the extracted text and replace everything, but in this case you'll loose all the other text formating (and I suppose that's not what you are looking for).
below the code that I used (not totally functional)

```
function main() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  Logger.log(body.getText());
//  body.setText("toto est content et il va ajouter des double stars ** et encore ** et encore **");
//  var search = body.findText('\*{2}.*?\*{2}');
  var pattern = '/(\*\*)/';
   var search = body.findText(pattern);
  Logger.log(search);
  if (search == null) {
   // DocumentApp.getUi().alert('No text was found that required formatting.');
  } else {
    var style = {};
    style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;
    search.
    search.getElement().setAttributes(style);
//    body.replaceText('\*\*','');
   // DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Formatting completed!');
  }
}
```

Comment: It's odd that that pattern should only return one. Perhaps a separate .findText function may be appropriate? Something like:

`var one = body.findText('\*');
 var two = body.findText('\*',one);
 var content = body.findText('.*\*',two);
 // [whatever bold code becomes appropriate];
 body.replaceText('\*\*','');`

Of course, that would rely on the first regex working as intended (unlikely) and would only pick up the first instance, which may not work given the `.replaceText` is working in the whole body.